# Oracle SQL Takes Forever - Timeout Aborted

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is taking forever and won't bring any result (timeout). Not sure what's going on, it worked perfectly until very recently.
The amount of data on the tables is large but not extreme (200k rows, max cols: 8).
This is my query, can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong please?

```
SELECT distinct

T.MY_ITEM_ID,
T.MY_ITEM_NAME,

T.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,

T.CITY,
T.STATE,
T.COUNTRY,

Apr28.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_03282022,
Apr28.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_03282022,
Apr28.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_03282022,

Apr06.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_04062022,
Apr06.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_04062022,
Apr06.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_04062022,

Apr13.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_04132022,
Apr13.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_04132022,
Apr13.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_04132022,

Apr20.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_04202022,
Apr20.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_04202022,
Apr20.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_04202022,

May02.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_05022022,
May02.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_05022022,
May02.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_05022022,

May09.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_05092022,
May09.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_05092022,
May09.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_05092022,

May16.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_05162022,
May16.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_05162022,
May16.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_05162022,

May23.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_05232022,
May23.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_05232022,
May23.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_05232022,

May30.MY_ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID_05302022,
May30.MY_ITEM_NAME AS ITEM_NAME_05302022,
May30.MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION AS MY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION_05302022

FROM MY_TABLE T

LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_03_28_2022   Apr28    ON T.KEY = Apr28.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_04_06_2022 Apr06 ON T.MY_KEY = Apr06.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_04_13_2022 Apr13 ON T.MY_KEY = Apr13.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_04_20_2022 Apr20 ON T.MY_KEY = Apr20.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_05_02_2022 May02 ON T.KEY = May02.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_05_09_2022 May09 ON T.KEY = May09.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_05_16_2022 May16 ON T.KEY = May16.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_05_23_2022 May23 ON T.KEY = May23.MY_KEY
LEFT JOIN ITEM_Snap_05_30_2022 May30 ON T.KEY = May30.MY_KEY
```

Thanks!

Comment: please take a look at the section about perfomance https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: My guess would be that something caused the query to start using a poor query plan.  You haven't posted the current plan or the plan that worked historically so we have no idea what might have changed.

Comment: Please include the execution plan of the query.